# Pagination and MySQL ResultSet

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am developing a website in php/MySQL. Say this is a website for my students to check their course/subject results online of their respective semester. The logic is as follows.
The semester.php page lists semesters one through eight. The students clicks on the their semester link and are taken to courses.php where links to all the courses/subjects in that semester are given. When they click on any of their subject, subjectresult.php opens showing results of all the students in that subject.

I am passing semester and subject values as parameters in the URL as follows.

courses.php?semester=semestername

I am also using pagination to display only 10 results per page.

So far so good. The subjectresult.php shows only 10 results with pagination links at the bottom. Everything nice and tidy.

My problem is that when I click on page 2, everything goes away because the subject parameters is now no longer in the URL.
The two URLs as under:
course/subject URL: subjectresult.php?sub=subjectname
page # URL: subjectresult.php?page_no=pagenumber

The workaround that I have made is that I have changed the paging links logic and have added subject name as a second parameter. Now everything is working fine and the partial URL is as under:
subjectresult.php?sub=subjectname&page_no=pagenumber

Please note that I am a novice, still learning.

Now I have a few questions.
Am I doing it right? (Which I don't think so)
How to store my subject_result query result when the subjectresult.php page loads for the first time so that I don't have pass this again and again with each paging link?

Or in a Nutshell..How to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simple answer is to use $_SESSION to store values that need to persist, or to use a form for the pagination with hidden fields for the values.

Comment: @Sloan Thanks for the answer but for me it needs some explanation.

Comment: That's what Google is for ;-). Seriously, lookup the $_SESSION variable. Since you didn't include any code in your question, I can't offer specific code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to review the help section on how to ask a question to get more useful answers, and the types of questions appropriate on SO.

Comment: @Sloan Thanks again. That's what I'll be doing next. I like your comments and since I am new to your community, it might take a while before I can do it the right way.

Comment: No problem. We all learned the hard way ;-). Glad you're here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approch is ok. 
If you want to store and reuse the subject value,
In PHP use a session variable.
Eg:

```
session_start();
// give the subject value to the session variable. 
$_SESSION['subject'] = "subject";
// get the value from the session variable if needed.
```

Like

```
session_start();
$subject = $_SESSION['subject'];
```

for more about sessions please check [here..](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Thanks Archu for the answer. I shall try to work on that. Hopefully this is what I might be looking for.